# Windows: Deleted Python37-32 and cannot use pip or Jupyter

Tags: windows-10, python

I do not use Windows normally (Honestly do not like at all).

I had multiple python version on my pc and I deleted Python37-32 (I know silly)

Now I cannot use `Jupyter notebook` on Windows PowerShell:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried to install jupyter but says: `Requirement already satisfied:`

I know I can use Anaconda but I need to use some different packages and only I can download with `pip`

So how can I fix the problem

Where jupyter: `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`
Where python : `C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Uninstall the Windows Python app.
2. Install your preferred version of Python from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). I would currently recommend [Python 3.7.5](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-375/). It is the latest version that isn't Python 3.8, which (at the time of this writing) has a limited amount of compatible modules available via `pip` ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/)).
3. During installation, choose a custom setup. Select the options to:

   - Install `pip`.
   - Install Python for all users.
   - Add Python to your environment variables.
   - Install Python into a custom non-Windows folder such as e.g. `C:\Programs\Python37` (avoid `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)` and your `User` directory).

[image: Python - Custom Installation Screenshot 1]

[image: Python - Custom Installation Screenshot 2]

4. After installation is complete, open the Windows Search and type `env`. Select the link that appears to edit your Windows environment variables.
5. Make certain you have an entry for both your primary Python installation folder and the Python `Scripts` subfolder present in your environment (path) variables e.g. `C:\Programs\Python37` and `C:\Programs\Python37\Scripts` (`Scripts` is where `pip.exe` is located).
6. Restart your computer, then run `python -m pip install jupyter`. Or, if you just want notebook, try `python -m pip install notebook`.

---